# Как реализовать запись на услугу через форму 1-С Битрикс

Tags: php, mysql, битрикс

Как реализовать форму записи на приём на сайте Битрикс?

Смысл такой , авторизованный пользователь через простую форму выбирает услугу из cписка и жмёт кнопку записаться.

А затем может просматривать их в личном кабинете.

Так же эти записи должны либо быть видны в админке, либо отрпавляться на почту администратору.

Что посоветуете?

Comment: Вы уже все расписали) Что тут еще можно посоветовать? Всю логику вы знаете, теперь только фантазия))

Comment: @Mully Мой вопрос в том  как это правильно реализуется  в Битрикс?

Comment: Через веб-форму и список результатов.

Answer (score 2):

1. Создаете ИБ "Запись на прием".
   1.1. Создаете св-во привязка к Услуге (тип список, или тип привязка к элементам ИБ, если у вас есть ИБ Услуг).
   1.2. Назначаете права (только авторизованным).
2. В разделе Личного кабинета (/personal/ обычно) создаете новую страницу или раздел с index.php.
   2.1. Создаете пункт меню в персональном разделе на созданную страницу "Запись на прием".
   2.2. На новой странице размещаете компонент bitrix:iblock.element.add "Добавление элементов инфоблока"
   2.3. Внимательно настраиваете компонент и тестируете.

ИБ - это инфоблок